# How to create a record from one to one relationship reverse direction in Django?

Tags: python, django, models

`Django` offers `Related objects` for `oneToMany` or `manyToMany` relationship.

Using this object, It can create a record from the reverse direction.

(for example with `XXXX_set.create(.....)` or `XXXX_set.get_or_create(.....)`)

I want to use this kind of function with an `oneToOne` relationship.

Is there any way to create an `one to one` relationship record from the reverse direction ?

for example

If `class A(models.Models)` and `class B(models.Model)` are tied by `one to one` relationship and I create `A` and save() it, than I want to create `B` also through `A`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way of doing that because there is no `queryset` between class A and class B, like it was with `ManyToMany` or `ForeignKey`. You must create `B` directly and assign `A` to proper field on `B`.